# Dynamically select Drop Down in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have 4 Drop Downs.

[image]

Each drop by default has a --select-- option. Each box has a unique id. As you can see, the second drop down is disabled if the above drop down value is --select--. It will only enable when the value is anything but --select--

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#idOfTheFirstDropDown').bind('change', function() {
    var options = $(this).children('option');
    var item = $('div.c-select').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
    var value = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length );
    //console.log(value);
    if (value.length) { // if selected 
        item.show(); // show the next dropdown
    }
}).trigger('change');
});
```

I want it to show the next dropdown only when my previous drop down value is **not** --select--. My code is taking in the first drop down but not changing the value. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

My HTML for one drop down box. Only the ID's change for the remaining 3. Rest of the HTML remains the same.

```
<div class="c-select">
<select name="list1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'list1\',\'\')', 0)" id="idOfTheFirstDropDown" class="GroupDD dropDown ">
<option selected="selected" value="">-- Select --</option>
<option value="1">Group1</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier if You could provide HTML.

Comment: @HubertS: Thank you for your suggestion. I have added HTML for the first drop down.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than hiding the options, I would use the disable attribute (comments in code):

```js
var selects = $('.drop-down');
selects.not(':eq(0)').prop('disabled', true); // disable all but first drop down

selects.on('change', function() {
  var select = $(this),
      currentIndex = selects.index(select),
      nextIndex = currentIndex + 1;
  
  // only do this if it is not last select
  if (currentIndex != selects.length - 1) { 
    selects.slice(nextIndex)        // get all selects after current one
           .val('')                 // reset value
           .prop('disabled', true); // disable 
    
    selects.eq(nextIndex).prop('disabled', select.val() === ''); // disable / enable next select based on val
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select><br>
<select class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select><br>
<select class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select><br>
<select class="drop-down">
  <option value="">--Select--</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. For some reason, it does not work for me. I have updated my HTML in my question. Can you figure out something from that?

Comment: All your selects have to have the same class, which you should use in the selector.  Also what version of jQuery are you using because you seem to be using a deprecated function (`.bind`)

Comment: They have the same class (.c-select). Also, I need to automate the code. Like just hit enter in console and it should automatically take the values other than select. Am I missing a line to do that? If yes, can you please update your code accordingly? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this one;

HTML code:

```
<select id="sel-1"></select>
<select id="sel-2"></select>
<select id="sel-3"></select>
<select id="sel-4"></select>
```

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("[id^=sel]").change(function(){

           /*
           *  find out the current box id
           */

           var id=$(this).attr("id");
           /*
           *  find out the current box id order number
           */

           var ordernumber=id.split("-")[1];

           if($(this).val()!="select")
           {
                 //enable next one
                 $("#sel-"+(ordernumber+1)).show();
           }
     })
})
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you please explain your comments? How am I to find the current ID?

Comment: var id=$(this).attr("id"); - this will give you current id

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the option that has `'--select--'` as text has no value, just use [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) on the handler to check if the selected option is other than the empty

```
if(this.val() !== '') {
// enable following select
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  select {
    margin: 5px 0;
    display: block;
  }
</style>
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.cls-select').change(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == '--select--') {

        // reset and disable the next drop downs
        $('.cls-select:gt(' + $('.cls-select').index($(this)) + ')').val('--select--').prop('disabled', true)

      } else {

        // current drop down has value so enable the next drop down
        $(this).next().prop('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  })
</script>

<select class="cls-select">
  <option>--select--</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
<select class="cls-select" disabled>
  <option>--select--</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
<select class="cls-select" disabled>
  <option>--select--</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
<select class="cls-select" disabled>
  <option>--select--</option>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```